# What is the exact relation between $\mathrm{SU(3)}$ flavour symmetry and the Gell-Mann–Nishijima relation

Tags: standard-model, conservation-laws, group-representations, lie-algebra, isospin-symmetry

I'm trying to understand how the [Gell-Mann–Nishijima relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann%E2%80%93Nishijima_formula) has been derived:
\begin{equation}
Q = I_3 + \frac{Y}{2}
\end{equation}
where $Q$ is the electric charge of the quarks, $I_3$ is the isospin quantum number and $Y$ is the hypercharge given by:
\begin{equation}
Y = B + S
\end{equation}
where $B$ is the baryon number and $S$ is the strangeness number.

Most books (I have looked at) discuss the Gell-Mann–Nishijima in relation to the approximate global $\mathrm{SU(3)}$  flavour symmetry that is associated with the up-,down- and strange-quark at high enough energies. But I have yet to fully understand the connection between the Gell-Mann–Nishijima and the $\mathrm{SU(3)}$ flavour symmetry.

Can the Gell-Mann–Nishijima relation somehow been derived or has it simply been postulated by noticing the relation between $Q$, $I_3$ and $Y$? If it can be derived, then I would be very grateful if someone can give a brief outline of how it is derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the formula only appeared empirically in 1956, before the eightfold way, for hadrons, long before quarks; and was seen to be such a basic fact that it informed the way flavor *SU(3)* was put together; and was subsequently spatchcocked into the gauge sector of the EW theory a decade after that--hence the alarming asymmetry of the hyper charge values.

Its basic point is that isomultiplets entail laddering of charge, $I_3$ being traceless, but in the early days of flavor physics, with *just* the strange quark, an isosinglet required its charge to be read by something,
and so was incorporated into the 3rd component of Gell-Mann's diagonal $\lambda_8$, providing the needed 2nd element of its Cartan sub algebra.

Note that, in left-right flavor physics, say after the introduction of the charmed quark, *C* came as an addition to the strangeness, additively in the hypercharge, so (*S+C+B*)/2, whereas in the left-handed sector of the EW theory charm and strangeness (and *T* and *B*-ness) are in weak isodoublets,
having escaped the hypercharge pen!

Answer (score 2):

The Gell-Mann–Nishijima relation arises from electroweak symmetry breaking. If we vev our Higgs SU(2) doublet,
$$
\langle(\phi^+, \phi^0)\rangle = (0, v/\sqrt{2}),
$$
we find that the theory remains invariant under a combination of the diagonal, Cartan SU(2) generator, the weak hypercharge, and the hypercharge, $Y$, because
$$
e^{iQ} \langle(\phi^+, \phi^0)\rangle = \langle(\phi^+, \phi^0)\rangle\\
Q \langle(\phi^+, \phi^0)\rangle = (T_3 + Y/2) \langle(\phi^+, \phi^0)\rangle = 0
$$
because on our Higgs doublet,
$$
T_3 + Y/2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 0\\
0 & -1/2\end{array}\right) +
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 0\\
0 & 1/2\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$
One can always find a combination of the U(1) and Cartan generator of SU(2)   which annihilates the vacuum. This form of the relation and these hypercharge assignments are a convention. The general form is $Q=T+aY$, with $a$ determined from the the hypercharge of the Higgs boson.

Comment: PS, sorry if I am telling you things you already know, I'm not sure whether you expected a deeper answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the feeling (although I am not sure) that the Gell-Mann–Nishijima relation (originally proposed in 1953 by Nishijima and 1956 by Gell-Mann) is something used to build the standard model, rather than that the standard model can be used to predict the the Gell-Mann–Nishijima relation.

Comment: Well the hypercharges are picked to give the correct integer electric charges. But I wouldn't say that the GM-N relation was more fundamental than the SM gauge group and spontaneous symmetry breaking pattern.

Comment: Yeah, but the GM-N formula has been derived before (or at the start of) the development of the Standard Model. Thus, it seems backwards to explain the GM-N formula using the Standard Model.

Comment: @innisfree: Here you assume the Higgs has hypercharge of $1$. Is there a way to prove that the Higgs has a hypercharge of $1$ without knowing that $Q= T_3+Y/2$?

Comment: The Higgs hypercharge is not relevant? It could have been anything. I'd still have been able to find a linear combination of Y and $T_3$ that gave zero. But then I'd also have to change hypercharge assignments of all the quarks and leptons to give the right electric charges. Let's say I can always find $Q=T_3 +aY$, with $a$ a constant chosen by convention. Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: The most natural hypercharge assignments are arguably those originating from a GUT.